# Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}

Tags: errors, tex-core, missing

I've gone through quite a number of the "Missing number, treated as zero" Q&As without any resolution.

I am using a dissertation template which is required by my college but unsupported. In downloading the tex file and running it I receive the following error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
```

I've tried to troubleshoot the error by commenting out each package accordingly. This particular error disappears (and then I get a number of other errors which makes sense since the template requires this package) when I comment out the required style file:

```
\usepackage{gmudissertation}
```

...so I'm pretty sure there's some kind of conflict between the .tex file and the .sty file or perhaps the problem is just old un-updated code in the sty file. I'm new to LaTeX.

Would anyone be willing to give me some hints on how to troubleshoot or proceed? I'm attaching the code for the template and the style file just in case anything jumps out at anyone.

Template

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{report}

%%  The file ``gmudissertation.sty''  is the GMU latex style file and
%%   should be placed in the same directory as your LaTeX files
\usepackage{gmudissertation}

%%
%% other packages that need to be loaded
%%
\usepackage{graphicx}                    %   for imported graphics
\usepackage{amsmath}                     %%
\usepackage{amsfonts}                    %%  for AMS mathematics
\usepackage{amssymb}                     %%
\usepackage{amsthm}                      %%
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}              %   a nice standard underline package
\usepackage[noadjust,verbose,sort]{cite} %   arranges reference citations neatly
\usepackage{setspace}                    %   for line spacing commands
\usepackage{environ}

%% The file ``mydissertationabbrev.sty'' is an (optional) personalized file that
%% may contain any and all LaTeX command (re)definitions that will be used
%% throughout the document
%%\usepackage{mydissertationabbrev}

\beforedoc

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

%% In this section, all of the user-specific fields to be used in the
%% title pages are set
\title{First line of the title\\
            second line of the title}
\onelinetitle{The complete title is to be repeated here without any line
        breaks for the second page and for the abstract page}
\author{Author}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\doctype{Dissertation}
\dept{(Name of Department)}
\discipline{(Discipline)}

\seconddeg{Master of Science}
\seconddegschool{My Former School}
\seconddegyear{Year of second degree}

\firstdeg{Bachelor of Science}
\firstdegschool{My Other Former School}
\firstdegyear{Year of first degree}

\degreeyear{Year}

% Note: semester name should be written in its full-form. For example, Fall Semester, not just Fall.
\degreesemester{Semester}

\advisor{Advisor}

\firstmember{First Member}

\secondmember{Second Member}

\thirdmember{Third Member}

\depthead{Department Head}

% The current dean is Lloyd J. Griffiths
\deanITE{Dean's Name}

%%
%% Introductory pages
%%

% Note: The signature sheet is set according to the requirements of the Volgenau School of
% Information Technology and Engineering. If your college/school requirement is different,
% please make appropriate changes in the "signaturepage" section of gmudissertation.sty file.
\signaturepage

\titlepage

% copyright technically optional but should be included in to avoid potential pagination problems
\copyrightpage

%%
%% Dedication page
%%

\dedicationpage

\noindent I dedicate this dissertation to ...
I dedicate this dissertation to ...

\acknowledgementspage

\noindent I would like to thank the following people who made this possible ...
I would like to thank the following people who made this possible ...

%%
%% Table of contents, list of tables, and lists of figures
%%

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

%%
%% Abstract
%%
\abstractpage

The first page of the abstract

\abstractmultiplepage

The second page of the abstract

\startofchapters

%% include the chapters one by one (or paste the chapter text in directly if desired)
\include{chapterOne}
\include{chapterTwo}

%% Note: appendix is now put before bibliography.
%% include the following directives if there are any appendices
\appendix
\appendixeqnumbering
\include{Appendix}

%%
%%  bibliography
%%

%% list all of the BibTeX files here for the WinEdt project (if applicable)
%GATHER{bibfile.bib}

%% any bibliography style can be used, but IEEEtran.bst is ideally suited to
%% electrical engineering references

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEfull,bibfile}

%%
%% curriculum vitae
%%
\cvpage

\noindent Include your \emph{curriculum vitae} here detailing your background,
education, and professional experience.
\end{document}
```

Style File:

```
%
%     ===========================
% === definitions of new commands ===
%     ===========================
%

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

%
% --- spacing, etc. ---
%
\newcommand{\nl}{\vskip 0.0pc}
\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent}
\newcommand{\emp}[1]{{\bf {#1}}}
\newcommand{\capt}[1]{\caption{\small {\it {#1}}}}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{assum}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}[section]
\newcommand{\ls}[1]
   {\dimen0=\fontdimen6\the\font
    \lineskip=#1\dimen0
    \advance\lineskip.5\fontdimen5\the\font
    \advance\lineskip-\dimen0
    \lineskiplimit=.9\lineskip
    \baselineskip=\lineskip
    \advance\baselineskip\dimen0
    \normallineskip\lineskip
    \normallineskiplimit\lineskiplimit
    \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
    \ignorespaces
   }

%%%%%
%%%%%   SETUP MARGINS AND PENALTIES NEEDED FOR GMU DISSERTATION
%%%%%


% CAS parameters
\def\siglinelength{2.8 in} % was 3.0 in
\def\spacesiglinename{0.5 cm}
\def\datelinelength{5.96 cm} % was 6.65 cm
\def\siglinedepth{0.4pt}
\def\intercommspace{0.20in}
\def\commdatespace{0.45in}

\def\tableSpace{\vskip 0.3in}
\def\figSpace{\vskip 0.3in}

\def\siglinewithspace{\rule{\siglinelength}{\siglinedepth} \hspace{\spacesiglinename}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering \large TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centering \large LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centering \large LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\centering \large ABSTRACT}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\hspace{2.225 in} \large CHAPTER}

% We need 1" margins except on the binding edge, where it is 1 1/2"
% Theses may be either single or double sided
\if@twoside
    \setlength\oddsidemargin   {36.1\p@}
    \setlength\evensidemargin  {0\p@}
    \setlength\marginparwidth {40\p@}
\else
    \setlength\oddsidemargin   {36.1\p@}
    \setlength\evensidemargin  {36.1\p@}
    \setlength\marginparwidth  {40\p@}
\fi

\marginparsep 10pt
%\oddsidemargin 0.5in \evensidemargin 0in
%\marginparwidth 40pt

% CAS additions
% \voffset -0.5in
% \headheight 0in
% \headsep 0.75in
% \textheight 8.5in
% \footskip 0in
%%%

% 11/06/03 additions
\voffset -0.5in

%%%%%%%

% 11/07/03 additions
\topmargin 0pt
\headsep .5625in
\textheight 8.6in
\textwidth 6in
\footskip 21pt


% Disallow page breaks at hyphens (this will give some underfull vbox's,
% so an alternative is to use \brokenpenalty=100 and manually search
% for and fix such page breaks)
\brokenpenalty=10000

%%%%%
%%%%%   SETUP COMMANDS PECULIAR TO THESES
%%%%%

% \author, \title are defined in report; here are the rest of the
% front matter defining macros
\def\onelinetitle#1{\gdef\@onelinetitle{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\doctype#1{\gdef\@doctype{#1}}
\def\chapterOneTitle#1{\gdef\@chapterOneTitle{#1}}
\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\discipline#1{\gdef\@discipline{#1}} % Needed after the degree title in the title page (Muhammad Abdulla)
\def\advis@r{Adviser} % default spelling
\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@advisor{#1}}
\def\firstmember#1{\gdef\@firstmember{#1}}
\def\secondmember#1{\gdef\@secondmember{#1}}
\def\thirdmember#1{\gdef\@thirdmember{#1}}
\def\fourthmember#1{\gdef\@fourthmember{#1}}
\def\depthead#1{\gdef\@depthead{#1}}
\def\deanITE#1{\gdef\@deanITE{#1}}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}
%\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % \author, \title in report
\def\firstdeg#1{\gdef\@firstdeg{#1}}
\def\firstdegschool#1{\gdef\@firstdegschool{#1}}
\def\firstdegyear#1{\gdef\@firstdegyear{#1}}
\def\seconddeg#1{\gdef\@seconddeg{#1}}
\def\seconddegschool#1{\gdef\@seconddegschool{#1}}
\def\seconddegyear#1{\gdef\@seconddegyear{#1}}
\def\degreesemester#1{\gdef\@degreesemester{#1}}
\def\degreeyear#1{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}}
\def\abstract#1{\gdef\@abstract{#1}}
% needed only for dual language departments
\def\language#1{\gdef\@language{#1}} \def\@language{babel}
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{Computer Science}\def\@discipline{Computer Science}
\def\@advisor{}\def\@firstmember{*}\def\@secondmember{*}
\def\@thirdmember{*}
\def\@fourthmember{*}
% \def\@submitdate{\ifcase\the\month\or
%   January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
%   July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
%   \space \number\the\year}
% \ifnum\month>8
%     \@tempcnta=\year \advance\@tempcnta by 1
%     \edef\@copyrightyear{\number\the\@tempcnta}
% \else
%     \def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
% \fi
\newif\ifcopyright 
\newif\iffigurespage \newif\iftablespage
\newif\ifthesiscopyright
\copyrighttrue \figurespagetrue \tablespagetrue
\thesiscopyrighttrue

\def\@standardsub{submitted to the department of \lowercase\expandafter{\@dept}\\
                and the committee on graduate studies}
\def\@standardend{}

\def\committeethesis{\let\@whichsub=\@committeesub}
\def\programthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@programsub}
\def\educationthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@educationsub}
\def\businessthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@businesssub}
\def\lawthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@lawsub}
\def\humanitiesthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@humanitiessub%
\let\@whichend=\@humanitiesend}
\def\specialthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@specialsub%
\let\@whichend=\@specialend}
\def\industrialthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@industrialsub%
\let\@whichend=\@industrialend}
\def\dualthesis{\let\@whichsub=\@dualsub%
\let\@whichend=\@dualend}

\let\@whichend=\@standardend
\let\@whichsub=\@standardsub

\def\beforedoc{
    %
    % --- spacing and page numbering
    %

    \markright{}
    \pagestyle{myheadings}
}


\def\signaturepage{%
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \pagestyle{plain}
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \null\vskip .5825in %\vskip .01in%
        \begin{center}
                \rm\uline{\uppercase\expandafter{\@title}}\\
                \normalsize
                \bigskip by \\
                \bigskip \@author \\
                %\bigskip
                A \@doctype\ \\
                Submitted to the\\
                Graduate Faculty\\
                of\\
                George Mason University\\
                In Partial fulfillment of\\
                The Requirements for the Degree\\
                of\\
                \@degree\\
                \@discipline\\[0.5 in]
        \end{center}
        Committee:\\[16 pt]
        \siglinewithspace \@advisor, \@doctype\ Director \\[\intercommspace]
        \siglinewithspace \@firstmember, Committee Member        \\[\intercommspace]
        \siglinewithspace \@secondmember, Committee Member       \\[\intercommspace]
        \siglinewithspace \@thirdmember, Committee Member        \\[\intercommspace]
        \siglinewithspace \@depthead, Department Chair\\[\intercommspace]
        % \phantom{\siglinewithspace\!\!} of \@dept \\ % commented out as requested by thesis office (Muhammad Abdulla)
        \siglinewithspace \@deanITE, Dean, The Volgenau School \\
        \phantom{\siglinewithspace\!\!} of Information Technology and Engineering \\[\intercommspace]
%         \siglinewithspace \@programdirector, Associate Dean \\
%          \phantom{\siglinewithspace} for Graduate Studies and Research \\[\commdatespace]
        Date: \rule{\datelinelength}{\siglinedepth} \hspace{\spacesiglinename} \!\!\@degreesemester\
%       Semester
        \@degreeyear\\
%         % optional fourth member
%         \if*\@fourthmember
%         \else
%             \rule{\siglinelength}{\siglinedepth} \qquad \@fourthmember
%             \\[\intercommspace]
%         \fi
        \phantom{Date: \rule{\datelinelength}{\siglinedepth} \hspace{\spacesiglinename} \!\!}George Mason University \\
        \phantom{Date: \rule{\datelinelength}{\siglinedepth} \hspace{\spacesiglinename} \!\!}Fairfax, VA
       \newpage
}

\def\titlepage{%
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \null\vskip .5825in %\vskip -0.1in%
        \begin{center}
                \rm\expandafter{\@onelinetitle}\\[10 pt]
        \end{center}
        A \lowercase\expandafter{\@doctype} submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for
            the degree of \\ \@degree\ at George Mason University \\[10 pt]%[35 pt]
        \begin{center}
        By \\[35 pt]
        \@author \\
%        \if\@seconddeg % comment the following three lines out if you don't have a second degree
             \@seconddeg\\
             \@seconddegschool , \@seconddegyear
        \\
%        \fi
        \@firstdeg\\
        \@firstdegschool , \@firstdegyear
        \\[39 pt]
        Director: \@advisor, Professor \\
        Department of \@dept \\[35 pt]
        \@degreesemester\
        %Semester
        \@degreeyear \\
        George Mason University \\
        Fairfax, VA
        \end{center}

        \vfill
        \newpage
}

\def\copyrightpage{%
        %\pagestyle{myheadings} % commented out to force page numbers to bottom center (8/11/07 change by C. St. Jean)
        \null\vspace*{2.375 in}%{1.6875 in}%{2 in} %{2.125 in}
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \setcounter{page}{2}
        \begin{center}
                %\large
                Copyright\ \copyright\ \@degreeyear\ by \@author\\
                All Rights Reserved
        \end{center}
        \vfill\newpage
}

\def\beforepreface{
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \pagestyle{plain}
        \signaturepage
        \titlepage
        %\ifcopyright\ifthesiscopyright\thesiscopyrightpage\else\tradcopyrightpage\fi\fi
}

\def\dedicationpage{%
        \lineskiplimit=1pc
        %\baselineskip=1pc
        %\lineskip=1pc
        % replacing the two lines above with the following line so that the lineskip
        % for dedictaion page is  single spaced. (Muhammad Abdulla)
        \ls{1}

        \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
        \setcounter{page}{3}

       % \chapter*{Dedication\@mkboth {DEDICATION}{DEDICATION}}
       % \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}

       % \vspace*{0.63in}
       \vspace*{.30 in}%{0.175 in}

        \begin{center}
        {\Large \bf Dedication}
        \end{center}
        \vskip 2.93 pc
}

\def\acknowledgementspage{%

        \ls{1}

        \pagebreak
        \vspace*{0.30 in}%{0.175 in}%\vspace*{0.63in}
        \begin{center}
        {\Large \bf Acknowledgments}
        \end{center}
        \vskip 2.73 pc
}

\def\startofchapters{%
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    %\ls{2}
    % replacing this with the \doublespacing command from setspace package, as
    % the \ls macro above makes text in figure captions and footnotes double
    % spaced, which is undesirable. setspace package avoid this. (Muhammad Abdulla)
    \doublespacing
    \setcounter{page}{0}
}


%
% --- chapters ---
%

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
        %    \numberline{\thechapter} \bf #1}  %% USE FOR BOLD TOC!!!!!!
            \numberline{\thechapter} #1}
      \else
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
      \fi
   \chaptermark{#1}
%  \addtocontents{lof} {\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
%  \addtocontents{lot} {\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
   \if@twocolumn
           \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
     \else \@makechapterhead{#2}%
           \@afterheading
     \fi}

\def\@schapter#1{
        \refstepcounter{chapter}
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
        \numberline{}\hspace*{-0.25in}#1}
   \chaptermark{#1}
%  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}}
%  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}}
   \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]
        \else \@makeschapterhead{#1}
              \@afterheading\fi}


\def\l@chapter{\vskip 0.0em plus 1pt
        %\bf
        \@dottedtocline{0}{0.0em}{1.35em}
}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    \vspace*{0.27 in}%{0.75in}
%%%    \centerline{\Large \bf \@chapapp{} \thechapter
    \begin{center}
     {\Large \bf Chapter \thechapter
    \Large \bf
%%%   \space : #1} \par
    : #1} \par
\end{center}
    \nobreak
    \vskip 22 pt %40pt
  }

}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    \vspace*{0.6 in}%{0.75in}
    \centering{\Large \bf #1} \par
    \nobreak
    \vskip 40pt
  }
}

%
% --- appendix chapters ---
%

\def\appchapter[#1]#2{
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
        %\numberline{\thechapter} \bf  #1} %% USE FOR BOLD TOC!!!
        \numberline{\thechapter} #1}
\else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\fi
   \chaptermark{#1}
%  \addtocontents{lof} {\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
%  \addtocontents{lot} {\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
   \if@twocolumn
           \@topnewpage[\@makeappchapterhead{#2}]%
     \else \@makeappchapterhead{#2}%
           \@afterheading
     \fi}

\def\@makeappchapterhead#1{
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    %\vspace*{0.27 in}%{0.75in}
    \vspace*{-0.48 in} % changing top margin of appendix from 2" to 1.25" (Muhammad Abdulla)
%%%    \centerline{\Large \bf \@chapapp{} \thechapter
    \begin{center}
     {\Large \bf Appendix \thechapter
    \Large \bf
%%%   \space : #1} \par
    : #1} \par
\end{center}
    \nobreak
    \vskip 22 pt %40pt
  }

}

\def\@makeappschapterhead#1{
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    \vspace*{0.6 in}%{0.75in}
    \centering{\Large \bf #1} \par
    \nobreak
    \vskip 40pt
  }
}

%
% --- secondary chapters
%

\def\chapt{\clearpage      % Starts new page.
   %\thispagestyle{plain}     % Page style of chapter page is 'plain'
   \global\@topnum\z@        % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
   \@afterindentfalse        % Suppresses indent in first paragraph.  Change
   \secdef\@chapt\@schapt   % to \@afterindenttrue to have indent.
}

\def\@chapt[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
        \numberline{}\hspace*{-0.25in}#1}\else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace*{-0.25in}#1}\fi
   \chaptermark{#1}
%  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}} % Adds between-chapter space
%  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}} % to lists of figs & tables.
   \if@twocolumn                                 % Tests for two-column mode.
           \@topnewpage[\@makechapthead{#2}]
     \else \@makechapthead{#2}
           \@afterheading                  % Routine called after chapter and
     \fi}                                  % section heading.

\def\chaptnontoc{\clearpage      % Starts new page.
   %\thispagestyle{plain}     % Page style of chapter page is 'plain'
   \global\@topnum\z@        % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
   \@afterindentfalse        % Suppresses indent in first paragraph.  Change
   \secdef\@chaptnontoc\@schapt   % to \@afterindenttrue to have indent.
}

\def\@chaptnontoc[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect \numberline{}\hspace*{-0.25in}#1}
        \else
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace*{-0.25in}#1}
        \fi
   \chaptermark{#1}
%  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}} % Adds between-chapter space
%  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{0pt}} % to lists of figs & tables.
   \if@twocolumn                                 % Tests for two-column mode.
           \@topnewpage[\@makechapthead{#2}]
     \else \@makechapthead{#2}
           \@afterheading                  % Routine called after chapter and
     \fi                                   % section heading.
}




\def\@schapt#1{\if@twocolumn \@topnewpage[\@makeschapthead{#1}]
        \else \@makeschapthead{#1}
              \@afterheading\fi}

\def\@makechapthead#1{
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    \vspace*{0.625in}%{0.75in}
    \centering{\Large \bf #1} \par
    \nobreak
    \vskip 50pt
  } }

\def\@makeschapthead#1{
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    \vspace*{0.625in}%{0.75in}
    \centering{\Large \bf #1} \par
    \nobreak
    \vskip 50pt
  }
}

%
% --- table of contents ---
%

\def\tableofcontents{
    \baselineskip=0.25pc
    \lineskip=0.25pc
    \lineskiplimit=0.25pc
    \@restonecolfalse
    \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \fi
    \chapt*{Table of Contents\@mkboth{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
    \vskip -0.83 pc
    \hfill Page \par
    \lineskip=0.7pc     %%% USE FOR WIDER SPACING TOC
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol
        \twocolumn
    \fi
    \lineskip=0.25pc   %%% USE FOR WIDER SPACING TOC
}


% --List of Tables
% captiontable - a tabular environment nested within a table environment with
%                a label, an optional List of Tables entry and a caption

\def\captiontable#1{
 \@ifnextchar [{\@captiontable{#1}}{\@dblarg{\@captiontable{#1}}}}

\def\@captiontable#1[#2]#3{
 \def\@captionlabel{#1}
 \def\@captionlistentry{#2}
 \def\@captionheading{#3}
 \begin{table}
 \centering }

\def\endcaptiontable{
% \spacing{1}
 \caption [\@captionlistentry]{\@captionheading}
 \label {\@captionlabel}
 \vspace*{7.6in}
 \end{table}}


\def\listoftables{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  %\fi\chaptnontoc{List of Tables\@mkboth
  % make "List of Tables" appear in Table of Contents (Muhammad Abdulla)
  \fi\chapt{List of Tables\@mkboth
   {LIST OF TABLES}{LIST OF TABLES}}
   \vskip -0.83 pc
   Table \hfill Page \par
   \lineskip=0.7pc  %%% USE FOR WIDER SPACING LOT
   \@starttoc{lot}
   \if @restonecol
   \twocolumn
   \fi
   \lineskip=0.25pc  %%% USE FOR WIDER SPACING LOT
}

%
% --- list of figures ---
%

\def\listoffigures{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \fi
  %\chaptnontoc{List of Figures\@mkboth
  % make "List of Tables" appear in Table of Contents (Muhammad Abdulla)
  \chapt{List of Figures\@mkboth
   {LIST OF FIGURES}{LIST OF FIGURES}}
   \vskip -0.83 pc
   \vspace*{-0.05in}
   Figure \hfill Page \par
   \lineskip=0.7pc  %%% USE FOR WIDER SPACING LOF
   \@starttoc{lof}\if@restonecol
   \twocolumn\fi
   \lineskip=0.25pc  %%% USE FOR WIDER SPACING LOF
}

%
% --- abstract
%

\def\abstractpage{
    \pagebreak
    \baselineskip=0.25pc
    \lineskip=0.25pc
    \lineskiplimit=0.25pc

    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \chapt{Abstract}

    \baselineskip=1pc
    \lineskip=1pc
    \lineskiplimit=1pc

    \vskip 0.25cm
    \noi
    \ls{1}
    \rm\uppercase\expandafter{\@onelinetitle}
    \nl

     \baselineskip=1pc
     \lineskip=1pc
     \lineskiplimit=1pc

    \noi
    \@author, PhD
    \nl

    \noi
    George Mason University, \@degreeyear
    \nl

    \noi
    \@doctype\ Director: \@advisor
    \nl

    \vskip 46pt
}

\def\abstractmultiplepage{
    \pagebreak \thispagestyle{empty}
}

\def\appendixeqnumbering {
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
}

%
% --- bibliography
%

\def\thebibliography#1{
\ls{1}
\chapter*{Bibliography\@mkboth
  {BIBLIOGRAPHY}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}}
  \markright{}
  %\thispagestyle{myheadings} % commented out to force page numbers to bottom center (8/11/07 change by C. St. Jean)
  %\thispagestyle{empty}
  \pagebreak
  \vskip 50pt
  \vspace*{0.61 in}%{0.75in}
  \centering{\Large \bf Bibliography}\par \nobreak
  %\vskip 40pt
  \vskip 55pt
  \list
  {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

%
% --- curriculum vitae
%

\def\cvpage{%
        \pagebreak
        \vspace*{.26 in}
        \begin{center}
        {\Large \bf Curriculum Vitae}
        \end{center}
        \vskip 43 pt
        \ls{1}
        \noindent
}

% we can send console reminder messages to the user here
% Added by Muhammad Abdulla
\AtEndDocument{
\typeout{}%
\typeout{======================== Attention ===============================}%
\typeout{}%
\typeout{The signature lines are different for each College/School of}%
\typeout{George Mason University.}%
\typeout{}%
\typeout{The current signature page is set according to the requirements} %
\typeout{of the School of Information Technology and Engineering.}%
\typeout{Students of other colleges/schools may need to manipulate the}%
\typeout{"signaturepage" section of the gmudissertation.sty file in order}%
\typeout{for the signature page to be formatted correctly.}%
\typeout{}%
\typeout{==================================================================}%
\typeout{}%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This template looks horrible and it is not astonishing something goes wrong. Just a question: Are you allowed to share this style file (cf. licensing)?

Comment: ASK the people who gave you the template to fix the Problem.

Comment: To troubleshoot I would add \tracingmacros=1 before \begin{document}  and \tracingmacros=0 behind. Then compile and check in the log-file if I can guess the cause of the error. If not I would try to remove more things from the example (and the style) and look again. When the failing example reaches a size of a "minimal example" and still fails and I still don't know "why" I ask a question. Beside this: @Johannes_B is right, if someone force you to use a template it is their job to give support.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome TeXnician. Yes, I'm allowed to share it. In fact it's a public package in TexLive. I agree with you Johannes and Ulrike, but I just needed to get it done. Your comments were helpful and led to the answer below! Thank you!!

Comment: these files are unsigned, neither licensed nor supported. complain loudly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer's recommendation of using \tracingmacros I was able to quickly find the troublesome line by going through the log file. Here was the issue:

```
%\def\language#1{\gdef\@language{#1}}
```

I think the syntax was not correct. Commenting out this line (from the style file) allowed the template to operate normally, and it was not needed since it tries to define a second language which isn't needed in my case.

I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: `\language` is a primitive of TeX; redefining it is *very* dangerous.

Comment: I wish I had seen this earlier. I did a manual Binary Search on the sty file, commenting and uncommenting blocks of lines to find it:) What I don't understand, and that is the reason I ended up visiting this post, is why redefining \language is so problematic, while redefining many other primary commands is not. Does anyone have any ideas?